# countable generated left ideal

Tags: ideals, semigroups

in Wikipedia i read that: Every  finitely generated group must be countable. why this is true?

if we change group condition to genererated left ideal, this ideal is countable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an uncountable group (or monoid) $G$. Then the left ideal generated by $1$ is $G$, which is not countable.